# JavaScript dom.style.display not working at all

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a button in my HTML and when I click that button, I want to remove some elements from the page.

currently I have a function something like this which sets the listener for that button.

```
function addListener_close(elem,i){
console.log("IN BUTTON");
elem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    //this returns 'block' which is the current display
    console.log(document.getElementById("newsentry-author").style.display); 
    //set the display to none
    document.getElementById("newsentry-author").style.display = "none"; 
    //this returns 'none' which is the new value
    console.log(document.getElementById("newsentry-author").style.display);
});}
```

However, in my HTML page, none of the elements' style changed after I click the button.

Where did I do wrong?

### UPDATE HTML CODE

```
            <div class="newsentry-clicked">
                <img class= "newsimage" src="https://dynaimage.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/digital-images/org/044409cb-e6f2-4c5b-8eaf-26078a4edef2.jpg">
                <div class="newsentry-text">
                <div class="newsentry-title">Commuting in the time of coronavirus in the nation's largest subway system</div>
                <div class="newsentry-author"><span style="font-weight: bold">Author: </span>Lebron James</div>
                <div class="newsentry-source"><span style="font-weight: bold">Source: </span>google.com</div>
                <div class="newsentry-date"><span style="font-weight: bold">Date: </span>2020/03/02</div>
                <div class="newsentry-desc-clicked">Crowded trains each weekday carry more than 5 million people hardened by terror threats and track-dwelling rats, daylight assaults and diluvial water main breaks. COVID-19 is their latest worry. The spread of the virus has unleashed anxiety across the nation'…</div>
                <a href="www.google.com">See Original Post</a>
            </div>
            <div class="close-button">×</div>
```

The function is bound to .close-button using javascript addEventListener

Comment: Is that all of your code? Because that's a function, and unless you call it, it won't do anything. It looks like you're seeing console output, so how you're calling that function is crucial but missing from the question. Like this it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/a5gLf0hv/

Comment: May you also share the HTML you’ve used?

Comment: I am calling the function using a button, I will upload my html code

Comment: You either use `<button onclick="execute-some-JS-func-when-clicked(this);">....</button>` or you attach a listener to a button in your JS. Last line in your JS should be something like: `addListener_close(document.querySelector('css-class-or-id-of-button'), the-i-value-whatever-that-is); ` Of course you have read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) already, and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) too, no doubt...

Comment: You need an "elem" variable which will deterimine the selector your JS will listen to. Right now that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah I did. I have a seperate js file which has a function, I didn't post my whole javascript code because it's way too long. I did the same thing for the other elements (i have a div that when click it makes some elements appear) and it worked, this button is the only one that is not working.

Comment: I am passing an argument into "elem" at somewhere else of my js code, and I made sure it is the right elem by doing console.log

Comment: You need a complete, and reproducible example here to get the best help possible...